# How to know specific string exist or not in PowerShell?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops

I want to verify the database for the given script in CI.
I want to check specific string exists or not in the given file.

Below is the content of my file
`USE [SampleDB]`

I am reading the content of my file and checking [SampleDB] string exists or not in the file.

I have tried the below things.

```
If(Get-Content -path D:/Document/admin.sql | Select-String -Pattern "[SampleDB]")
{
  # Right Database exist
} else {
  # Right Database does not exist
}
```

How can I verify the right database name after the USE string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Select-String` uses *regular expressions* to perform string searches, and the construct `[...]` has a special meaning in that context - namely, it means "match any one of these characters", not quite what you're expecting.

To search for the word `[SampleDB]` verbatim you either have to escape it correctly:

```
# escape your search term!
$searchTerm = [regex]::Escape('[SampleDB]')

if(Get-Content -path D:/Document/admin.sql | Select-String -Pattern $searchTerm) {
  # Right Database exist
} else {
  # Right Database does not exist
}
```

... or you can request `Select-String` perform a non-regex match with the `-SimpleMatch` switch:

```
if(Get-Content -path D:/Document/admin.sql | Select-String -Pattern "[SampleDB]" -SimpleMatch) {
  # Right Database exist
} else {
  # Right Database does not exist
}
```